# Date formatting according to country habbits

Tags: java, date, time, format, simpledateformat

We create J2SE application that has to format the date and time according to custom the country from which users come from. I want to ask how to solve this thing in Java? Probably I'll use SimpleDateFormat, but I wonder if it is possible to get format string in somehow simpler way than to have all format strings for each country separately.

Comment: You can use DateFormat With locale if you have to show the date in same format for each country .i.e . DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, locale).format(new Date());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateFormat` *already* allows you to do this - just use [`DateTimeFormat.getDateTimeInstance(dateStyle, timeStyle, locale)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateTimeInstance%28int,%20int,%20java.util.Locale%29) or something similar, depending on your needs.

Comment: yes, I tried it and this is the solution to my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

Use [`DateTimeFormatter.#ofLocalizedDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDate-java.time.format.FormatStyle-) to get a locale specific date format for the ISO chronology.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.FormatStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtfDateFull = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL)
                .localizedBy(new Locale("cs", "CZ"));
        DateTimeFormatter dtfDateMedium = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
                .localizedBy(new Locale("cs", "CZ"));
        DateTimeFormatter dtfDateShort = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT)
                .localizedBy(new Locale("cs", "CZ"));

        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Prague"));

        System.out.println(date.format(dtfDateFull));
        System.out.println(date.format(dtfDateMedium));
        System.out.println(date.format(dtfDateShort));
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run:**

```
neděle 18. července 2021
18. 7. 2021
18.07.21
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/3b2hkQ)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>